# Hibernate Envers unable to extend DefaultRevisionEntity

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to extend the DefaultRevisionEntity in order to add a username to the current revision entity. However, instead of simply adding the new field, it's creating a completely new table. Code is as follows

AuditRevisionEntity

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;

@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditRevisionListener.class)
public class AuditRevisionEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {
    private String user;

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

AuditRevisionListener

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionListener;

public class AuditRevisionListener implements RevisionListener {

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        AuditRevisionEntity rev = (AuditRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;
        rev.setUser("MYUSER");
    }
}
```

User

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank()
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @NotBlank()
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

}
```

Resulting in

[image]

Comment: compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-envers', version: '5.3.7.Final'

Answer (score 0):

Your custom RevisionEntity is missing the required **@RevisionEntity** annotation.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;

@Entity
@RevisionEntity( AuditRevisionListener.class )
public class AuditRevisionEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {
    private String user;

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

More info and a code sample can be found in the  [Envers documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#envers-revisionlog)

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but its still adding a new table instead of just adding a new field

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have fixed this with adding the table to the custom entity pointing to the main revinfo table

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity( AuditRevisionListener.class )
@Table(name = "revinfo")
public class AuditRevisionEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {
    private String user;

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```